In avalonia for android, how do i get the size of my view?
I have a simple application in Avalonia with a MainView (which is a UserControl automatically created by the template) and not much in it.
I can start it on the android emulator, and it works, but it doesn't seem to have a width.
I added a log after the view gets loaded, but it seems that the width is somehow not calculated. I only get NaN.
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += this.MainView_Loaded;
}

private void MainView_Loaded(object? sender, Avalonia.Interactivity.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{this.Width}");
}

Is there a way to force this calculation or read the Width properly for an android device ?
I also tried to execute platform-specific code to get the view width and write it somewhere, but i couldn't find an entry point from MainActivity.cs to execute code after the App gets created.

It seems that Width is not used at all when running on Android ?
There is another property Bounds which does the same thing, just more annoying to use:
private void MainView_PropertyChanged(object? sender, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Property.Name)
    {
        case "Bounds":
            Debug.WriteLine($"{((Rect)e.NewValue!).Width};
            break;
    }
}

